# jQuery Load not parsing HTML Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I would like to build a list of articles with a different thumbnail for each one, and this thumbnail should be loaded using jquery.load, but I have one problem:

The class of each article's thumbnail in html is as follows:

```
thumb{ARTICLE_ID}
```

Now, given this basic example:

```
<i class="thumb{ARTICLE_ID}"></i>
<script>$('thumb{ARTICLE_ID}').load("https://somewebsites.com .itemimg");</script>
```

How can I Make jQuery parse "{ARTICLE_ID}" variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way, for example:

```
<i class="thumbnail" data-article-id="{ARTICLE_ID}"></i>

<script>
  $('.thumbnail').each(function () {
    $(this).load("https://somewebsites.com/" + $(this).data('article-id'))
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is not working, no console errors, but nothing is loading. Shouldn't 'article-id' be before the .load?

Comment: Provide here your exact code. Problem is unfortunately on your side, this script works.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I started a chat with you, if you have time, thanks again.